# road extraction from image

Tags: java, image-processing

i am doing project of final year in that i Extract road from image .in that i take image ,  image can be segment into three
different cluster by using k-means clustering algorithm that [image
divide into three different cluster](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3NXvf.jpg) after i tried to select
longest connected component cluster from that image but not getting
what  i want .i want to delete all the portion from that image (Except
Road)or want to visible only road from that image . how can do that

Input image:

[image: Input Image]

Output Image:

[image: Output Image]

My code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.Kernel;
import java.awt.image.ConvolveOp;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class design1 {
    static BufferedImage image;
    static int[] histogram = new int[256];

    public void makeHistogram() throws IOException {
        image = ImageIO.read(new File("input.png"));
        for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
            histogram[i] = 0;
        for (int h = 0; h < image.getHeight(); h++) {
            for (int w = 0; w < image.getWidth(); w++) {
                Color color = new Color(image.getRGB(w, h));
                int greyvalue = color.getRed();
                histogram[greyvalue] += 1;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        new Kmeans1(image, 3, histogram);
    }

}
```

k-mean clustering

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class Kmeans1 {
    BufferedImage image_temp;
    boolean not_terminated;
    int loops, changedPixels;
    int[] histogram;
    static int count = 0;
    int[] lowerbounds = new int[3];
    static int g = 0;
    int[] lb = new int[3];
    int[] ub = new int[3];
    int[] mean = new int[3];
    BufferedImage imaged;
    BufferedImage thresholdimage, dilateimage;

    public Kmeans1(BufferedImage image, int bins, int[] histogram)
            throws IOException {
        this.histogram = histogram;
        initialize(image, bins);
        calcbounds();

        // / calculateMean(histogram);
        processImage(image, bins);
        imaged = returnimage();
        imageWrite();
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            System.out.println("LB" + j + "=" + lb[j] + " UB" + j + "=" + ub[j]
                    + " Means" + j + "=" + mean[j]);
        }
    }

    public void initialize(BufferedImage image, int bins) {
        image_temp = image;
        not_terminated = true;
        mean[0] = 173;
        mean[1] = 100;
        mean[2] = 112;
    }

    public int createmean(BufferedImage image, int i, int bins) {
        int pixelindex = 0;
        int sum = 0;
        int value = 0;
        for (int h = 0; h < image.getHeight(); h++) {
            for (int w = 0; w < image.getWidth(); w++) {
                try {
                    pixelindex += 1;
                    if (pixelindex % bins == i) {
                        Color rgb = new Color(image.getRGB(w, h));
                        sum += rgb.getRed();
                        value += 1;
                        count++;
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return sum / value;

    }

    public void calcbounds() {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            int lb1 = calculatelb(j);
            int ub1 = calculateub(j);
            lowerbounds[j] = lb1;
            lb[j] = lb1;
            ub[j] = ub1;
        }

    }

    private int calculatelb(int index) {
        int cMean = mean[index];
        int currentBound = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            if (cMean > mean[i]) {
                currentBound = Math.max((cMean + mean[i]) / 2, currentBound);
            } else {
            }
        }
        return currentBound;
    }

    private int calculateub(int index) {
        int cMean = mean[index];
        int currentBound = 255;
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            if (cMean < mean[i]) {
                currentBound = Math.min((cMean + mean[i]) / 2, currentBound);
            } else {
            }
        }
        return currentBound;
    }

    private void processImage(BufferedImage image, int bins) {
        int delta = 255 / (bins - 1);

        for (int h = 0; h < image.getHeight(); h++) {
            for (int w = 0; w < image.getWidth(); w++)

            {
                Color rgb = new Color(image.getRGB(w, h));
                int grey = rgb.getRed();

                for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                    if (grey > lb[i] && grey < ub[i]) {
                        g = i * delta;
                        image_temp.setRGB(w, h, (new Color(g, g, g)).getRGB());
                    } else {
                        image_temp.setRGB(w, h, (new Color(g, g, g)).getRGB());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public BufferedImage returnimage() {
        return image_temp;
    }

    // BufferedImage img1=image_temp;
    public void imageWrite() throws IOException {
        // BufferedImage img1=image_temp;
        ImageIO.write(imaged, "jpg", new File("output.jpg"));
        System.out.println("image write completed");
    }


}
```

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Post some code, a sample image, and an image/drawing of what you want your code to detect.

Comment: Please add the code to your question with proper formatting, make sure it's runnable (i.e. has a `main` method) and provide a sample image as input. Also add an image/drawing to your question that explains what exactly your expected output looks like and explain how your current code falls short of it.

Comment: I tried to convert your comments to edits - but there appeared to be syntax errors. Please edit the question with the code.

Comment: What do you mean by you are not getting what you want? Meaning you do get something but it's false detection? Or it failed to segment the road out correctly? As Chris and Phillipp said, edit you post to include your codes, sample image as input, what your expected output look like. I also wish you for you to add something, the current results where you said you are not getting what you want. So at least from there, we can see if you are close or totally doing it wrong (: